# Bootstrap carousel disappearing (OpenCart)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, opencart

For some strange reason after a given time, the slides will just disappear (visually it looks like it deletes itself), when I watch it play out in the inspect element using chrome, it seems to get confused with the second slide. I am using OpenCart, would love some help.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div id="wcRandomProducts" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" >
        <div class="carousel-inner">
             <?php $pages = array_chunk( $products, 6); ?>              
            <?php foreach ($pages as  $k => $tproducts ) {   ?>
            <div class="item <?php if($k==0) {?>active<?php } ?>">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="product-thumb">
                 <?php foreach( $tproducts as $i => $product ) {  ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="col-item">
                            <div class="photo">
                               <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info">
                                 <div class="product-overhead"><h4>
                                      <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
                                       <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                                      <?php } else { ?>
                                      <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><i class="fa fa-scissors">&nbsp;</i> <?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
                                      <?php } ?>
                                      </h4>
                                 </div>     

                                  <div class="button-group">      
                                    <button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">ADD</span></button>
                                    <button class="alt" type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">INFO</span></button>
                                  </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php if( count($products) > 6 ) { ?>
        <div class="carousel-controls">
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#wcRandomProducts"   data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#wcRandomProducts"  data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>              
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#wcRandomProducts').carousel({
interval: 3500
})
</script>
```